# Match C++ Strings and String Literals using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match **Strings** (both between **double & single quotes**) and **String Literals** in **C++ source files**. I am using the `re` library in Python.

I have reached the point where I can match double quotes with `r'"(.*?)"'` but having trouble with the syntax for extending the above regex to also match the single quotes strings (confused with the `\` and how to escape the quotes in a Python regex).

Also, from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) I want to be able to match each of these cases:

- > " (unescaped_character|escaped_character)* "
- > L " (unescaped_character|escaped_character)* "
- > u8 " (unescaped_character|escaped_character)* "
- > u " (unescaped_character|escaped_character)* "
- > U " (unescaped_character|escaped_character)* "
- > prefix(optional) R "delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter"

I am so confused with regexes and all I try fail. Any suggestions and example code will be awesome for me to gain understanding and -hopefully- build all these regexes.

Comment: Do you also plan to match prefixes (`U`,`u8`, etc.)? Or do you need to tell one from another?

Comment: Ideally, it would be great to separate between all the literals and the other single or double quote strings. But if that is too complicated then its ok if I can simply match all of the strings above with one regex.

Comment: Try [`(?:\bu8|\b[LuU])?(?:"(?P<dbl>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'(?P<sngl>[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')|R"([^"]*)\((?P<raw>.*?)\)\3"`](https://regex101.com/r/gD4lV6/1).

Comment: Any update? Did it work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Sorry, was away. Trying to test it now but (because I am newbie in Python) when I paste your regex it complains.. is there a type on `r'(?:\bu8|\b[LuU])?(?:"(?P<dbl>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'(?P<sngl>[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')|R"([^"]*)\((?P<raw>.*?)\)\3"')` or am I doing something wrong??

Comment: Try [`p = re.compile(r'(?P<prefix>(?:\bu8|\b[LuU])?)(?:"(?P<dbl>[^"\\\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"|\'(?P<sngl>[^\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\'\\]*)*)\')|R"([^"(]*)\((?P<raw>.*?)\)\4"')`](https://ideone.com/KYkxwA)

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Yes, it works! If you could write it as an answer for me to accept, it would be great. Also, If it is not too much of a trouble, a brief explanation of your answer would be very good for my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab all the string literals with the following regex:

```
r'(?P<prefix>(?:\bu8|\b[LuU])?)(?:"(?P<dbl>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|\'(?P<sngl>[^\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\'\\]*)*)\')|R"([^"(]*)\((?P<raw>.*?)\)\4"'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQ9mU9/1)

**Explanation**:

- `(?P<prefix>(?:\bu8|\b[LuU])?)` - (Group named "prefix") the optional prefix, either `u8` (whole word) or `L`, `u`, `U` (as whole words)
- `(?:"(?P<dbl>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"` - a double quoted string literal, with the contents between `"` captured into Group named "dbl". The part is matching `"`, then 0+ characters other than `\` and `"` followed with any number (0+) of sequences of an escape sequence (`\\.`) followed with 0+ characters other than `\` and `"` (it is an unrolled version of `(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*`)
- `|` - or
- `\'(?P<sngl>[^\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\'\\]*)*)\')` - a single quoted string literal, with the contents between `'` captured into Group named "sngl". See details on how it works above.
- `|` - or
- `R"([^"(]*)\((?P<raw>.*?)\)\4"` - this is a raw string literal part capturing the contents into a group named `raw`. First, `R` is matched. Then `"` followed with 0+ characters other than `"` and `(` while capturing the delimiter value into Group 4 (as all named groups also have their numeric IDs), and then the inside conetents are matched with a lazy construct (use `re.S` if the strings are multiline), up to the first `)` followed with the contents of Group 4 (the raw string literal delimiter), and then the final `"`.

Sample [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KYkxwA):

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'(?P<prefix>(?:\bu8|\b[LuU])?)(?:"(?P<dbl>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|\'(?P<sngl>[^\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\'\\]*)*)\')|R"([^"(]*)\((?P<raw>.*?)\)\4"')
s = "\"text'\\\"here\"\nL'text\\'\"here'\nu8\"text'\\\"here\"\nu'text\\'\"here'\nU\"text'\\\"here\"\nR\"delimiter(text\"'\"here)delimiter\""
print(s)
print('--------- Regex works below ---------')
for x in p.finditer(s):
    if x.group("dbl"):
        print(x.group("dbl"))
    elif x.group("sngl"):
        print(x.group("sngl"))
    else:
        print(x.group("raw"))
```

Comment: Confused about the `^` in `\'(?P<sngl>[^\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\'\\]*)*)\')`. In the docs it says that is "matches the start of the string (...) or immediately after each newline". Does it have the same effect here? Do we need it since a single quote string may not start at the start of a string, correct?

Comment: `[^\'\\]*` = *0+ characters **other than** those inside the **negated character class***. So, it'll match `12sd#$%`, but not `'` and not ``\``.

Comment: @Wiktor Can you suggest how a negative lookbehind assertion can be used in order your regex to **not match strings which are inside comments** (i.e. strings which have somewhere behind them a `//` or `/*` and `*/`)?

Comment: Are you using PyPi `regex` or `re` module? If `re`, then you cannot use infinite width lookbehind. Just match the comments, but match and capture the string literals outside the comments.

Comment: I am using the `re` module. Then can you suggest if there is a way with regexes to separately match strings and comments? Perhaps, could we first match and fetch the comments and then match inside of them in case of a string..?

Comment: These are known and solved issues. Single line comments are usually matched with `r"//.*"` and multiline ones with `r"/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/"`

Comment: My question is how to combine both comment and string matching. If I understood correctly, you suggest to first match the comments (with `r"//.*|/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/"` and then the strings?

Comment: Yes,  the full one will look like `r'//.*|/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|(?P<prefix>(?:\bu8|\b[LuU])?)(?:"(?P<dbl>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|\'(?P<sngl>[^\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\'\\]*)*)\')|R"([^"(]*)\((?P<raw>.*?)\)\4"'`

Comment: @WiktorStribizew I think there is problem with the regex in the answer; namely the raw literal (e.g. `R"foo(
Hello
World
)foo";` is still matched by your regex even if I remove the `|R"([^"(]*)\((?P<raw>.*?)\)\4"` from it. Is that correct? I am trying to match only the raw literal so I want to use only the last part of the regex, hence my question. Could you please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Appreciate your quick response. I am afraid this does not work either, i.e. I have only used the regex you just provided and it still matches the raw literal.

Comment: Since raw string literals also may contain `'` and `"`, they need to be matched. If you can afford to use `regex` module, you could use the magic verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to really avoid getting them in the result. `re` is too poor.