# Skip start when exists between two things in regex

Tags: php, regex

hello this is my string

```
line('hello this is my \'first\' line')
line('hello this is my \'second\' line')
line('hello this is my \'third\' line')
line('hello this is my last line')
```

i want to use regex and get something like this

```
hello this is my \'first\' line
hello this is my \'second\' line
hello this is my \'third\' line
hello this is my last line
```

i am using this regex

```
line[(][']([^']*)['][)]
```

this regex just can get the last line because in each other lines `' '` exists. what should i do on this regex to get all line like result that i want?

**Just please edit `([^']*)` i just want to use this. (using start)**

Comment: if you are reading line wise, then it could have been done with (liitle modification) what I told yesterday

Comment: You need a part of [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597386/match-c-strings-and-string-literals-using-regex-in-python/36602277#36602277). See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/pW8sT9/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew also the comment you gave here :- (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646907/how-to-match-operator-separated-strings-in-sublime-package-development-yaml-tmla#comment60887421_36646907) with link (regex101.com/r/pC5wN5/2)

Comment: @rock321987: Yeah, too many almost-dupes.

Comment: @MyJustWorking Did you have a chance to try `"~line\\('[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*'\\)~"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/line\('(.*)'\)/", $string, $output_array);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fmb

Edit....
     preg_match_all("/line('([^']*)')/", $input_lines, $output_array);

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fmj

Comment: Just please edit ([^']*) i just want to use this. (using start)

Comment: @MyJustWorking So you downvoted me because I did not see and understand your edit? Seriously?? Well now that you know how the comment function works, use that instead of downvoting. I will update my answer now with what I think you want.

Comment: Ok. Sorry I missunderstod you.

Comment: Your last edit just get last line ! did you check it?

Comment: @MyJustWorking Yes I did check it. It didn't work. And the reason is the ^. That sign means start of line. I can't use that in the middle of the pattern. What is wrong with the pattern I suggested first?

Comment: ^ can be used if it's used as R.K's answer, at the start of the pattern and before line.

Answer (score -1):

Use this regular expression:

```
 ^line[\(][\'](.*)[\'][\)]$
```